# Is there a way to run a loop through the output of SQL transformation?

Tags: hana, sap-data-services

I have run the following in SQL transform in Data Services

```
select stag_table from op_schem.dataset where tx=23
```

This gave me 40 tables. Is there a way, I can do a `select * from <each stag_table>` on each of these 40 tables and load them into flat files?

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.

You write a SELECT statement for each of those tables and store the result into a file.

This question seems to be about the same problem your other questions where you decided to not provide feedback to the answers you received.

If you cannot be asked to write 40 SELECTS based on the same simple template `SELECT * FROM <table_name>` why not do what programmers do and automate this?

Just write a program that replaces the table name for all of the 40 tables. That'll take a few minutes and surely will be more effective than asking the same question in a different once more.